# How to make a better strategy for read database many time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am working on training a network that requires loading the image and its ground-truth data from dataset every iteration. Currently, I used the below strategy that read the image and its ground-truth every time from my SSD. The problem is that my images are *png with large size `(512x512x3)`, hence, it takes time to read these images. Also, the strategy repeated read the images in the dataset. Do we have a better strategy to do it faster, ie. load all images to RAM and access it from RAM is faster? I am using python3 and keras

```
class myDataset(Dataset):    

    def load_dataset(self, root_path):
        #Return a list of image and ground-truth

    def load_image(self, image_id):
        info = self.image_info[image_id]        
        image = skimage.io.imread(info["path"])        
        return image      

    def load_gt(self, image_id):
        #Load ground-truth data
        info = self.image_info[image_id]        
        gt_data = skimage.io.imread(info["path"])        
        return gt_data
#==========Preparing dataset, return a dict of image, mask path=====
dataset_train = myDataset()
dataset_train.load_dataset('./dataset')
dataset_train.prepare()
#==========Load image and its mask during training=================
for i in range (10000):
    #Let image_id be a random id from the dict
    image=dataset_train.load_image(image_id)
    gt_data=dataset_train.load_gt(image_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you‘re able to load all data into memory, than you should definetely do this. If you can do your preprocessing also before starting your training, it‘s even better and definetely the fastest option.( Just saw, that you‘re alreadydoing this)

If this is not the case: Do the preprocessing batch wise before the training and save the data serialized with pickle. Loading a pickle file should be much faster. Also consider using model.fit_generator instead of calling the fit method several times. You can write your own Generator class which only loads parts of the pictures. This class can inherit from python Sequence class. This is documented in the fit_generator function in pythons functional model API and is a really ellegant approach.